# How can I redirect to a loading page first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been reading the code all day and I can't figure out how to make a loading page.

What I would like to do is: once the link is created, redirect to a loading page (5 seconds for example) and then show it the link.

This is the index.js of the application

```
const notFoundPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public/404.html');

app.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id: slug } = req.params;
  try {
    const url = await urls.findOne({ slug });
    if (url) {
      return res.redirect(url.url);
    }
    return res.status(404).sendFile(notFoundPath);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).sendFile(notFoundPath);
  }
});

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  slug: yup.string().trim().matches(/^[\w\-]+$/i),
  url: yup.string().trim().url().required(),
});

app.post('/url', slowDown({
  windowMs: 30 * 1000,
  delayAfter: 2,
  delayMs: 500,
}), rateLimit({
  windowMs: 30 * 1000,
  max: 3,
}), async (req, res, next) => {
  let { slug, url } = req.body;
  try {
    await schema.validate({
      slug,
      url,
    });
    if (url.includes('xshorturl')) {
      throw new Error(' ERROR ');
    }
    if (!slug) {
      slug = nanoid(5);
    } else {
      const existing = await urls.findOne({ slug });
      if (existing) {
        throw new Error('Apodo en uso. ');
      }
    }
    slug = slug.toLowerCase();
    const newUrl = {
      url,
      slug,
    };
    const created = await urls.insert(newUrl);
    res.json(created);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).sendFile(notFoundPath);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (error.status) {
    res.status(error.status);
  } else {
    res.status(500);
  }
  res.json({
    message: error.message,
    stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '' : error.stack,
  });
});
```

[This is the main html of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ8Xa.png)

[This is the index.js of the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsyw6.png)

*I hope your help and thanks in advance.*

Comment: I don't think it is a good solution slow down server response. Its better use simple javascript on client side which uses settimeout function to redirect to url after.

Comment: @OsmanCorluk I've been seeing that, but I don't want to make the APP again. I would like to be able to do what I have in mind just as I have the APP done. Any ideas?

Comment: Can u please let me know in which exact line you want to slow down on server. So that I may find a solution.

Comment: @OsmanCorluk what I want to do is that when the shortened link is created, it redirects you to the Loading Page and after 5 seconds it shows you the link.
`return res.redirect(url.url);` -> this is when it shows you the shortened link

`res.json(created);` -> and this is when you render it to web

Comment: please checkout the slow-down documentation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-slow-down . What you want to do and whats slow-down do very different. Server side script is mostly for db or api interaction . You want to change user experience which can be done client side. Check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-redirect-a-page-to-another-page-in-html/  . Using meta tag is better option for you. But I still insist on using js settimeout

Comment: I will try, thanks